# Excel 2016 - compare two columns for match

Tags: excel, compare, match, excel-2016

I have two columns where I want to highlight differences [image]

I want to see if the letter in Column A exists in Column B - it should be case-sensitive, because there are C and c in column A

If there is a match I want the row preferably turn green - otherwise a OK / NOT OK in column C

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `FIND()` function. Try: `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2,B2)),"OK","NO")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this `Sub` to the `Worksheet` code pane. For this open the **Developer tab** and click **Visual Basic**. In the left pane select the worksheet where your datas are, and doubleclick it. Insert the code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Column = 1 And InStr(1, Target.Offset(0, 1).Value, Target.Value) > 0 Then
Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End If
If Target.Column = 2 Then
If InStr(1, Target.Value, Target.Offset(0, -1)) > 0 Then
Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End If
End If
End Sub
```

If the content change in column A or B the respective row color will change.